# Need python2 libvirt bindings on ubuntu 21.04(hirsute)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, libvirt

I am new to python packages and libraries. I have been working on upgrading ubuntu container from 14.04 to 21.04. There has been a dependency where many applications were written on python2 library and on ubuntu 21.04, python2 is deprecated and only python3 is supported. Using few blogs, somehow I am able to install python2 and made it as default. I need to install python2 libvirt binding on ubuntu 21.04. Please help me to install the same!

Please note, due to some dependencies, python3 is not recommended for the use.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Libvirt dropped support for Python 2 over 18 months ago now.

https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt-python/-/commit/b22e4f2441078aec048b9503fde2b45e78710ce1

Old versions of the libvirt-python binding are not likely to compile against currently releases of libvirt library. So you really do need to get over to using Python 3.